How can I do pagination to retrieve all salesforce marketing cloud automations via rest api?
I'm trying to return all the automations from all the orgs I have in salesforce marketing cloud through the following method:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { AutomationAuthService } from '../automation-auth/automation-auth.service';
import { OrgConfigService } from '../automation-auth/org-config.service';

@Injectable()
export class AutomationService {
  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private authService: AutomationAuthService,
    private orgConfigService: OrgConfigService,
  ) {}

  // Function that makes a SOAP request using the authentication service
  async makeSoapRequest(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.authService.makeSoapRequest();
  }

  // Function that retrieves and saves automations for different organizations
  async getAndSaveAutomations(): Promise<void> {
    // Get the organization IDs from the configuration service
    const orgIds = Object.keys(this.orgConfigService['orgs']);

    for (const orgId of orgIds) {
      const uniqueAutomations = new Map(); // Map to store unique automations by ID

      // Get the access token and organization credentials
      const token = await this.authService.getAccessToken(orgId);
      const orgCredentials = this.orgConfigService.getOrgCredentials(orgId);
      const apiUrl = `${orgCredentials.restUrl}/automation/v1/automations/`;

      let page = 1; // Start at the first page
      let hasMorePages = true; // Boolean to control pagination

      while (hasMorePages) { // Pagination loop
        try {
          const response = await firstValueFrom(
            this.httpService.get<any>(apiUrl, {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
              params: { page, pageSize: 25 }, // Pass the current page
            }),
          );

          const currentPageItems = response.data.items; // Get the automations from the current page
          console.log(`Page ${page} returned ${currentPageItems.length} items for org ${orgId}`);

          // Store unique items based on ID and log the collected items
          currentPageItems.forEach(item => {
            console.log(`Collected Automation ID: ${item.id}, Name


I also tried this other approach:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { AutomationAuthService } from '../automation-auth/automation-auth.service';
import { OrgConfigService } from '../automation-auth/org-config.service';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class AutomationService {
  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private authService: AutomationAuthService,
    private orgConfigService: OrgConfigService,
  ) {}

  // Function that makes a SOAP request using the authentication service
  async makeSoapRequest(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.authService.makeSoapRequest();
  }

  // Function that retrieves and saves automations for different organizations
  async getAndSaveAutomations(): Promise<void> {
    // Get the organization IDs from the configuration service
    const orgIds = Object.keys(this.orgConfigService['orgs']);

    for (const orgId of orgIds) {
      const uniqueAutomations = new Map(); // Map to store unique automations by ID

      // Get the access token and organization credentials
      const token = await this.authService.getAccessToken(orgId);
      const orgCredentials = this.orgConfigService.getOrgCredentials(orgId);
      const apiUrl = `${orgCredentials.restUrl}/automation/v1/automations/`;

      let page = 1; // Set the initial page for paginated request.
      let totalPages = 1; // Initialize with 1 page, will be updated after the first request

      try {
        do {
          const response = await firstValueFrom(
            this.httpService.get<any>(apiUrl, {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
              params: { page: 2, pageSize: 25 }, // Set page size to 25
            }),
          );

          const currentPageItems = response.data.items; // Get the automations from the current page
          console.log(`Page ${page} returned ${currentPageItems.length} items for org ${orgId}`);

          // Store unique items based on ID and log the collected items
          currentPageItems.forEach(item => {
            console.log(`Collected Automation ID: ${item.id}, Name: ${item.name}, Org: ${orgId}`);
            uniqueAutomations.set(item.id, item);
          });

          // Check if the first page has less than 25 items and if there are more pages
          if (page === 1 && currentPageItems.length < 25 && response.data.count > currentPageItems.length) {
            console.warn(`Warning: Page 1 for org ${orgId} has less than 25 items, but more items are available. Total items: ${response.data.count}`);
          }

          // Calculate the total number of pages based on the first page response
          if (page === 1) {
            totalPages = Math.ceil(response.data.count / 25); // Calculate the total number of pages
            console.log(`Total pages for org ${orgId}: ${totalPages}`);
          }

          console.log('Pagination:', page);
          page++; // Move to the next page
        } while (page <= totalPages); // Continue until all pages are collected

        const allAut = Array.from(uniqueAutomations.values()); // Convert the Map to an array of unique automations
        console.log(`Org ${orgId}: Total unique automations collected: ${allAut.length}`);

        // Here you can continue with processing, filtering, or saving the data...

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error processing org ${orgId}:`, error.message); // Log any error that occurs during the process
      }
    }
  }
}


In both cases the return is the first page repeated the total number of pages, for example, if org X has 5 pages in its return I will have 5 times the automations of the first page, I don't know if MKT has a different way of iterating over the pages using rest..well, whoever can help I appreciate it.

Just saying: Can you isolate your question to the relevant part? Especially since you are using nest.js , which is not something that we can easily reproduce from within a generic SFMC instance. -> You are making it way harder for us to help than necessary.

The pagination logic in this endpoint seems to be bugged right now.
I noticed that when increasing the $page parameter it does not really what I would expect it to - get to the next page of results. Instead it starts the returned results from the number contained in the parameter
For example, imagine there are 502 automations:

we set the $pageSize to 500
we get the $page=1 results which returns 500 items
we get the $page=2 results and we see the following:

the items contain 500 results again
the items happen start with the 2-nd item that was in the previously returned set (from $page=1)



This makes the $page parameter sort or work like an index of an array.
This is not the pagination logic we have in other endpoints and goes against what the endpoint documentation is saying, but is the logic that we have at the moment.

When discussing this on HowToSFMC Slack channel, @gortonington suggested this as a workaround:

For interim you can probably create some sort of calculation for pagination like: pagesize * (pagination-1) = page with:

pagesize being the page size (e.g. 500)
pagination being the actual page: 1 = 1-500, 2 = 501-1000
page being the index value of the object to start on



Thank you @Rafal and gortonington for sharing this. Definitely, this API has a bug and it is returning the same items although we specify the page parameter.

I tried and can confirm that the page calculation @gortonington shared is correct

Thak you @Rafal
